# prevent title from repeating

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have been messing around with a few [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) methods but, I can't seem to find one that works.

```
<div className="tags">
  {adv_event.types.map(type => (
    <div className="tag" key={type.tid}>
      <h5 className="body-color">Event Type:</h5>
      <Link to={`/events/category/${type.slug}`} className="home-link track-click">{type.name}</Link>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Right now `<h5 className="body-color">Event Type:</h5>` is repeated for every tag. Is there a way to show the title once without adding it before each tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it outside the loop?

```
<div className="tags">
  {adv_event.types.length > 0 ? (<h5 className="body-color">Event Type:</h5>) : ''}
  {adv_event.types.map(type => (
    <div className="tag" key={type.tid}>
      <Link to={`/events/category/${type.slug}`} className="home-link track-click">{type.name}</Link>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but when the there is no value for the link it just reads 'Event Type:'

Comment: @brooksrelyt updated the code above to check if the array has value and conditionally render with an && operator

Comment: Good idea, but now a 0 is displayed when there is no value

Comment: updated with a conditional operator, not sure why a 0 was shown though. try this